# How to create a synchronized version of Google Guava's TreeMultimap

Tags: java, guava

Does anyone know how to create a thread safe instance of TreeMultimap with 
`TreeMultimap.create()`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Guava [`Multimaps`](https://guava.dev/releases/29.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html) class contains static methods for creating and decorating Multimaps, similar to what the `Collections` class in java.util provides for Collections and Maps.

In your case, you should use:

```
Multimaps.synchronizedSortedSetMultimap(TreeMultimap.create())
```

Comment: note that the returned multimap will only have sorted *values*. not keys.

Comment: @lights that's the contract of SortedSetMultimap in general, not specific to this method. But if you use an implementation with sorted keys (e.g. [`TreeMultimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/29.0-jre/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html), then the synchronized wrapper will also be sorted.

Answer (score 8):

Similarly, if you need to get synchronized version of `ListMultiMap`, you could use:

```
Multimaps.synchronizedListMultimap(ArrayListMultimap.create());
```

Google Guava [Official doc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#synchronizedListMultimap(com.google.common.collect.ListMultimap))